# Java: Change color of an JPanel with fillRect

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to fill my Panel with an Rectangle to override the image. But with my code nothing happens. You know why? I dont want to use setBackground.

```
Graphics g = JPanel.getGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.fillRect(0, 0, window.drawPanel.getWidth(), window.drawPanel.getHeight());
```

Comment: `I dont want to use setBackground.` - why? That is the proper way to do it. You should never use the getGraphics() method to do painting. Use the API the way it was designed to be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the panel background with this way. You need to override paintComponent method like this.

```
JPanel jYourPanel = new JPanel(){
       @Override
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //lets paint background
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

      }
    }
```